# Difference between /usr/local and ~/.local

Tags: home-directory, installed-programs, directory-structure

I install **.zip** / **.tar.gz** programs in `~/.local/bin`, but Ubuntu have `/usr/local` directory with content same as in `~/.local`.

So, what is difference between this directories except for sudo access?

Comment: Is locale and local the same @Jeremy?

Comment: This answer in the flagged duplicate explains it pretty well: https://askubuntu.com/a/955971/3739

Comment: locale and local mean two different things. Locale refers to the place on earth you're from, whereas local is part of the directory structure. Edit: Sorry, I understand your question, good point

Comment: Is OP asking for locale or local? I think your misunderstanding the question!

Comment: @george Yep, good point, the answer linked in the comment is constructive none-the-less. I've dropped the flag.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: Not quite. The answers to your linked question focus on the “hidden” nature of dot-prefixed directories.

Comment: I'd vote for removing the "duplicate" flag. I think this question is more specific than the other one, and the answer is better, while [what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-local-in-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978654/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-local-in-ubuntu) asks for `local` vs `.local`, which is related but more vague, even though a good answer might address the purpose of specific folders.

Answer (score 8):

`/usr/local` is a place where software usable by all users can be installed by an administrator.

`~/.local/bin` is a place where a user can install software for their own use.

There is some messiness in the history of the directory structure used in different distros and communities, but this covers the basic differences.

Answer (score 4):

The `~/.local` is intented for user-only use for example by installing a 3rd-party software that does not come from the repositories in `~/.local/bin` you will have it access you and only you.

Whilst the `/usr/local` is intented for stuff that is used for more that one user. For example `/usr/local/bin` has executabled that are 3rd-party but from repositories and are available to all users.