# Moving a bash script to /bin directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script named  **Script.sh** . It worked well when it was in my */home* directory.I moved it to my */bin* directory,for running it as command. At first it worked well(as a command, in my */bin*), but after restarting, it stopped working. When I type `Script.sh` , in terminal, nothing happens and I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
 for getting the terminal to work again. When my **Script.sh** is in my */bin*, my `spd-say` command doesn't work either(it does not pronounce the argument when I use it in terminal). After moving the script from */bin*, everything gets corrected. Is there any problem, moving a file to */bin*?

```
$ echo $PATH
:/home/m/bin:/home/m/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

This is the first part of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
spd-say -w "Do you know this man?"
xdg-open $(locate "X.jpg")
read a
if [ "$a" == "yes" ]
then
spd-say -w "Call the police."
else
spd-say -w "Thanks."
fi
```

Comment: @Unbesiegbarkeit Is the script expecting some sort of input ? Does it operate on files where it's stored ? If possible, provide a minimal example of what it's supposed to do

Comment: In my /home directory it works, even in /bin it worked at first, but I don't know what has happened.

Comment: Are you saying that calling `spd-say` from the command line didn’t work when you had `Script.sh` in `/bin/`?

Comment: `spd-say` is most likely broken and stuck in an endless loop. Out of curiosity why test for "Yes" and not "Qui" instead?

Comment: You mean 'oui'? The script was in french and I modified it for sending it to the site. Then I found that all script is in french( the --language option,etc..). So I put it in french again and I forgot  to change that part.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  And what to do for fixing it? I mean is there any way to put the script in */bin* without having that probleme?

Comment: Your PATH has an empty entry at the start (before the first colon `:`). Maybe that's related?

Comment: This would be easier to troubleshoot with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you say you moved the script to `/bin/`, did you mean you moved it to `~/bin/`? There is a big difference. The script should be in `/home/$USER/bin/`, not `/bin/`.

Comment: By doing `ls  -a  | grep bin`  nothing shows up in my PC and I don't see such file there in my  */home* directory. Anyway, what happens if I put it in */bin* ? (The bin in my root directory I mean.) The same directory where commands like *ls* are there?

Comment: When your script hangs in /bin, can you open up another terminal and enter `pgrep spd-say`? Does it return a pid?

Comment: no, `spd-say` does not work in any terminal. Anyway I forgot putting the script there. Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

I have not enough reputation to make a comment, but it seems to me that you need to put your script in /usr/local/bin.

From `man hier(7)`

> ```
> /bin
>     This  directory contains executable programs which are needed in 
>     single user mode and to bring the system up or repair it.
>
> /usr/local/bin
>     Binaries for programs local to the site.
> ```

You know, copy with `sudo cp` and check the permissions.

But if you want to use the program just for yourself, put in on `/home/$USER/bin` folder.

Also, you can make a symlink from your script to a path in /usr/local/bin

```
ln -s /full/path/to/your-script.sh /usr/local/bin/<empty or optional name>
```

- [How to put executable to /usr/local/bin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877992/how-to-put-executable-to-usr-local-bin)
- [Differences between /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/sbin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux